# C# WinForms how to use a non-static string from one void to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

As a small beginner-ish project i'm making a simple program that can play **.wav files**, I've encountered an issue however where in stuck in a situation where the program gets the file path and name from one void but I need to use that string in another void, **example code her**e:

```
public void ChooseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            OpenFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
            OpenFile.FileName = "";
            OpenFile.Title = "Open .wav file";
            OpenFile.Filter = "wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
            OpenFile.ShowDialog();

            string fileName = OpenFile.FileName;
            ChosenFileText.Text = fileName;
        }

        public void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
            sound.Play();
        }
```

As you can see I need to use the fileName string with the SoundPlayer but currently **I get the error**:

> "The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context".

I've tried making it public and static but all I get is errors, does anyone know how I can work around this?

Comment: `fileName` is a local variable and will not be visible in `PlayButton_Click` method. You should make `fileName` a field at class level.

Comment: @sthotakura Aha I can't believe I didn't try that, works all good now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the variable inside the class so that everyone can access it.

```
string fileName="";

public void ChooseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            OpenFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
            OpenFile.FileName = "";
            OpenFile.Title = "Open .wav file";
            OpenFile.Filter = "wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
            OpenFile.ShowDialog();

            fileName = OpenFile.FileName;
            ChosenFileText.Text = fileName;
        }

        public void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
            sound.Play();
        }
```

Comment: I've done that and now im adding exception handling and i'm trying to declare the soundplayer right after the filename but im now getting an error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Player.fileName'". Do you know what to do?

Comment: @PhreshBrread The reason is that you can't use one instance variable to initialize another one using a field initializer. search error in google

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, I've changed some stuff and it seems to be working all good.